# Unable to create Windows 8.1 Apps Using Qt Libs

Tags: qt, windows-8.1, windows, appx, appxmanifest

I am trying to test an app I've created with Qt in Windows 8.1. And created deplorable binary as the instruction [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool).  I've followed this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh446767.aspx#create_package_using_dir), and created an appx package using the command.

```
MakeAppx.exe  pack /d C:/Users/user1/Documents/MyApp_Win-Sep-27-2014 /p C:/Users/user1/Documents/MyApp.appx
```

I've self signed the package using SignTool.exe and these commands.

```
MakeCert /n CN=myComp,O=myComp,L=miami,S=florida,C=us /r /h 0 /eku "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13" /e  10/13/2014 /sv vKey.pvk vKey.cer -r
Pvk2Pfx /pvk vKey.pvk /pi 123 /spc vKey.cer /pfx vKey.pfx /po 123
SignTool sign /a /v /fd SHA256 /f vKey.pfx /p 123 C:/Users/user1/Documents/MyApp.appx
Certutil -addStore TrustedPeople vKey.cer
```

But when I try to start my app, it just shows the splash screen only and nothing else.

Also. here is my AppManifest.xml, which I've created manually I'm not sure what should I specify for Entry Point in this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest">

  <Identity Name="myComp.vsoft.MyAppV1" 
            Version="1.0.0.0" 
            Publisher="CN=myComp, O=myComp, L=miami, S=florida, C=us" />  
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>MyApp</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>myComp</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>logo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Prerequisites>
    <OSMinVersion>6.1</OSMinVersion>
    <OSMaxVersionTested>6.3</OSMaxVersionTested>
  </Prerequisites>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="en-us" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="MyAppV1" Executable="MyApp-V1.exe" EntryPoint="MyApp-V1.App">
      <VisualElements DisplayName="MyApp" Description=" My First App"
           Logo="logo.png" SmallLogo="logo.png"  
           ForegroundText="dark" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
         <SplashScreen Image="logo.png" />
      </VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>



<Capabilities>   
  <Capability Name="internetClient"/>  
  <Capability Name="musicLibrary"/>
  <Capability Name="videosLibrary"/>
 <DeviceCapability Name="microphone"/>
  <DeviceCapability Name="webcam"/> 
</Capabilities>    
</Package>
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this documentation page](http://qt-project.org/wiki/WinRTBuild)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes right now I am trying with that, and I have successfully run the project using VS 2013, but I don't know   how to convert it to appx format, any idea?

Comment: no idea really, but maybe [this page](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-dev/winrt-support.html) contains useful info. It looks like it is a step you need to manually perform. But I have absolutely zero experience with this stuff.